# Cloudflare configuration with AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare

I'm trying to configure cloudflare dns to point to an elasticbeanstalk application.

Most of the tutorials are using route53 but I'm trying to see how it'll work with cloudflare

I bought a domain: **myapp.com** and it's already pointing to the cloudflare nameservers.

On the cloudflare there's NO dns record right now.

I can access the eb app by url :
**myapp-env.eba-uistqmhg.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com**

so how do i point myapp.com to the eb app ?

Do I simply add a *CNAME* that points to the eb url or I need to use the eb ipv4 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CNAME for `myapp-env.eba-uistqmhg.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. After making the change, it might take few minutes for the DNS to propogate.